# How to view transaction logs in oracle of recent sql commands executed by a hibernate enabled java program (with time and performance info)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, transactions

I am currently executing a java program which performs some jdbc commands like insert select etc.

My goal is to see how much time those individual commands are taking with performance impact too.

My program logs the sql commands in the seperate log file, but I need something database specific.

I want to see the performance and time taken by each command in the database view, As soon as I am finished with my program execution.

Is there any way available to achieve this? P.S. I am using Oracle SQL Developer for GUI purposes.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `v$sql`, `gv$sql`, `dba_hist_sqltext` views. Just select from this view and you will find interesting data. Filter and Sort them according to your need.

```
select * from v$sql;
```

You can join them with `v$session` or `gv$session` to fetch the session details who executed which sql.

Cheers!!