# How can I detect from where was set value in database?

Tags: java, database

It's a first time that I'm working on a big project and I can't find from where specific field receiving its values(setter wasn't used in code). Is there a way to find out this from database?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7KE8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the database itself, you can track the changes through Transaction Logs (check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58724202/how-to-view-transaction-logs-in-oracle-of-recent-sql-commands-executed-by-a-hibe) answer, for instance).

If this project relies on spring-boot or hibernate, I would, for the sake of testing, switch on SQL logging:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```